# The excerpt suffix won't go away

Tags: excerpt

I want to show the post content until the more tag, or if there's no more tag than just first n words. Something really basic, right? Obviously I need to use `get_the_excerpt` function. But the problem is that this function is behaving strangely. It adds a suffix to the end, that nobody wants. And you can't remove it!

You could in the pas do [this](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-remove-the-from-the-excerpt)

But this no longer works, because Wordpress decided to give us even more bad time with this by changing `[...]` to something like `[…]`

Now you can't even `str_replace` or `rtrim` that `[…]`. Trust me I tried.

The solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21340007/3-dots-at-the-end-of-the-excerpt-in-wordpress) works, but this only cuts text after n words. It ignores the more tag.

Another way would be to use `get_the_content`, but that just shows the full post content even if I select Summary in the Settings -> Reading.

So please, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excerpt has a maximum lenght of 55 words, so even if you try to cut your text at say 70 words, `the_excerpt()` will ignore that and only show 55 words.

To remove`[...]` from the read more tag, simply find `the_content()` and replace it with `the_content('',FALSE,'');`. You can also use `the_content('Read more...');`  to display a text after the read more tag, in this case `Read more...`.

If you need to remove `[...]` from the excerpt, you can do this in your functions.php

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

You can also add a custom text or link inside the `''` if you need something else to dispay

Comment: Tried the_content('Read more...') and the_content('',FALSE,''). They both show the entire content. So another mistery. :( But the snippet you provided works...thank you! So the "excerpt_more" is the keyword I was supposed to search for..

Comment: Just glad I could be of help. Enjoy